# Can a which-clause be used with another which in this sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses, possessive-of-which

Apologies for the unclear title, but I wasn't sure how to phrase it.

**Situation**
Assume a table, on which lies an object, occupying half of the table. A hat is placed on the table.


**Question**

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. *The hat was placed on the table, half of which was occupied by an object*
2. *The hat was placed on the table, **which** half of which was occupied by an object*

The second sentence feels so unnatural to me, but isn't the first one not quite right either? Though not ungrammatical, it has a ring of offering a rather parenthetical, separate clause rather than a clause describing the previous one (that is, reading the first sentence, I get an impression of "and by the way, half of the table was occupied by an object". Indeed, I feel a semi-colon rather than a comma would be preferable in that case).

Also consider the sentences

3. *The hat was placed on the table, which was occupied by an object*
4. *The hat was placed on the table, which was partly occupied by an object*

Any input on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to point out that although your 1, is better, neither really works. Would it be OK f you stuck to real, rather than constructed examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using **which** in either of your example sentences (between the two, the first sounds more natural) is that it's not entirely clear if **which** refers to **the hat** or to **the table**. We can assume it refers to the table, but it's possible that it doesn't.

One way of rephrasing the sentence is to remove the comma and use an adjectival phrase:

> The hat was placed on the table which was half-occupied by an object.

Without the comma, **which** is now easily parsed as applying to the table specifically.

---

But there is now another problem. Without the comma, the sentence implies that there is more than a single table and that, of all of the tables, the hat was placed on the one that was half-occupied by some object.

(If that actually is the intended meaning, then there is no problem.)

You mention using a semicolon. That would certainly be one way of removing this particular ambiguity:

> The hat was placed on the table; half of the table was occupied by an object.

This works but it's a bit long-winded.

---

Perhaps the most appropriate method of saying this is to reuse an earlier suggestion but simply change the definite article in front of **table** to the indefinite article:

> The hat was placed on a table which was half-occupied by an object.

This is concise, presents no ambiguity, and also doesn't convey the implication that there is necessarily more than a single table.